# What does surrender preferred shares mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean **exchange preferred shares** for **common shares**?

He exercised all of them in August 2017, and covered the $5 billion cost of doing so by surrendering virtually all of Berkshire's preferred shares.

Source: https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/warren-buffett-invested-5-billion-bank-of-america-made-fortune-2020-10-1029690339#

Comment: It would be helpful to give more context especially since if you use an adblocker (as I do) you will not be able to follow the link.

Comment: [***Preferred stock / shares**](https://quizlet.com/81219554/accounting-final-chapter-12-vocabulary-flash-cards/) - stock that entitles the holder to a fixed dividend, whose payment takes priority over that of ordinary share dividends*. Buffet ***sold*** (surrendered) his preference shares when they were no longer as profitable as holding an equal amount of equity in "common" (ordinary) shares.